# Ruby on Rails Terminal Executable Script Not Passing Arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, terminal

I'm on OSX 10.8 and i'm trying to execute a script from my home directory, `~`.

The script is to shorten the creation of a new rails app, e.g:

```
ruby new path/to/app
```

This is the alias in my `~/.profile`:

```
alias rc="~/.rubynew
```

And the contents of `.rubynew`, which have been run through `chmod 755 ~/.rubynew` are:

```
#!/bin/bash

$path="~/Documents/Rails_Apps/"

ruby new $path+=$1
```

---

### Further Information

**Executed as:**

```
rc helloworld
```

Should create an application with the path:

```
~/Documents/Rails_Apps/hellworld
```

I'm getting errors for these, which I use to compile c with gcc, in exactly the same method. I have Googled this for a good one hour and rewritten in 50 different ways and it refuses to work, any guesses?

`~/Documents/Rails_Apps` **does exist.**

```
Errors:

/Users/tsujp/.rubynew: line 3: =~/Documents/Rails_Apps/: No such file or directory
ruby: No such file or directory -- new (LoadError)
```

Comment: It's `rails new ...`, not `ruby new ...`

Comment: Ah, well fixing that still yields no result. It defaults back to the home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

First of all, I had `ruby new` instead of `rails new`

Secondly I didn't need to concatenate the lines in the script, this yields:

```
#!/bin/bash

rails new "~/Documents/Rails_Apps/"$1
```

It now works as intended.